# Reading a file by passing filename to a function

Tags: ruby, function, printing

I am trying to read the file name and process each line. How do I pass the file name to the the function?

```
puts "file name??  "
_file = get.chomps

def printFile(_file)
  do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      print_me = "Line 1 " + line
      return print_me
    end
  end
end
```

I am planning to pass `print_me` to another function like:

```
def thisWillPrint(print_me)
  new_print = print_me + " DONE! "
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few problems in your code. First you are using a block inside the definition of your printFile function which is a syntax error, next you use the variable f in that block which was never given a value, on top of that you try to do a loop on it and never open a file descriptor. Finally you must call the printFile function somewhere so that ruby knows it has to run it.

The first thing your printFile function should do is get a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to the file the user gives you as a string in the _file variable, this way you actually have a stream you can read lines from not just the string object. So I recommend you change the variable from _file to fileName, and leave file for the stream. You do this by using Ruby's own [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html) class and calling its [open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-open) method. As you can see from the documentation open can be called in a few different ways, but let's use a block like you were trying to do.

```
puts 'give me a path to a file'
fileName = gets.chomp

def printFile(fileName)
  counter = 0
  File.open(fileName) do |file|
    while line = file.gets
      print_me = "line " + counter.to_s + " "+line
      thisWillPrint(print_me)
    end
  end
end

def thisWillPrint(print_me)
  puts print_me + " DONE! "
end

printFile(fileName)
```

You also have to call the printFile function at the end so that ruby actually runs something.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by returning inside the loop, you will exit it as well. With the following, you will get the contents of the file.

```
    def printfile(filename)
      print_me = ""
      File.open(filename, "r") do |f|
        f.each {|line| print_me << line }
      end
      print_me
    end
```

For large files, the return variable will also be very large.

Answer (score 0):

To read a line from standard input you can use the `gets` method. The `gets` method captures a newline `\n` by default. You have to use the `chomp` method to get rid of the newline.

So to get the file's name from standard input you can do the following:

```
print "File's name? "
_file = gets.chomp
```

Inside the `printFile` method you can do the following:

```
def printFile(_file)
  print_me = ""
  File.foreach(_file) do |line|
    # process each line however you'd like inside this block
    # for example:
    print_me += line
  end
  return print_me # explicit return not required
end
```

Note that you do not have to explicity 'return' something if it's the last expression in the method. The last expression could have just been `print_me` instead.

You can pass what this method returns to another method like `thisWillPrint` like this:

```
def thisWillPrint(print_me)
  new_print = print_me + "Done!"
end

output = printFile(_file)
thisWillPrint(output)
```